# Update multiple columns in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I have a Dataframe which contains around 15 columns.
I need to update 4 columns with different values based on 3 conditions. I can easily do it in SQL using following SQL statement.

```
Update myTable SET 
   ( col_1,
    col_2,
    col_3,
    col4
   ) = 
   ( 'abc',
     'def',
     'ghi',
     'jkl'
    )
WHERE col_1 IS NULL and col_2 == 'ABC' AND col_10== 'XYZ'
```

How do I do that in PySpark using Dataframes?
I tried doing it via `withColumns`, but I can only do it for 1 column at a time.

Eg - `new_df = old_df.withColumn(col_1,F.when((old_df.col_1.isNull()) & old_df.col_2 == 'ABC' & (old_df.col_10 == XYZ)),'abc').otherwise(old_df.col_1)`

I need to update all 4 columns simultaneously in a single dataframe.

Comment: "withColumn" can be called several times, like "old_df.withColumn(..).withColumn(..)". Duplicated logical condition can be avoided by moving condition to variable.

Comment: Yes, in that case I need to make sure that I update `col_1` last, as `col_1` is also present in logical condition, otherwise `col_2`, `col_3`, `col_4` would never get updated as `col_1.isNull()` condition would never be met